# How to install ansible yum packages in order

Tags: ansible, yum

I have:

```
  ignore_errors: false
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  yum:
    name: ["epel-release", "clamav"]
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
```

It complains that no package found, but I need to install epel-release before I can install clamav because it lives in epel repo. Is there a way to ensure the order? What are the options besides splitting to 2 stanzas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible loop can solve like below.

```
ignore_errors: false
become: yes
become_method: sudo
yum:
  name: "{{ item }}"
  state: present
  update_cache: yes
loop:
  - "epel-release"
  - "clamav"
```

Comment: Since I'm new to SO, I can not comment @Zeitounator's answer so I'm commenting here. His point is correct. Due to documentation, loops are less efficient and there's even below notes that exactly answers your question.    
[yum module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes)    
_However, if one of the packages adds a new yum repository that the other packages come from (such as epel-release) then that package needs to be installed in a separate task. _

Answer (score 2):

Although using a loop as proposed by @Haldum should effectively solve your issue, its use is discouraged in [`yum` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes). Since you definitely need to add the epel repo prior to using it, I would create two tasks where you can eventually install several packages in the second.

```yaml
- name: install my things
  hosts: my_hostgroup
  become: true

  vars:
    my_packages:
      - clamav
      # - some other package maybe

  tasks:
    - name: Install prerequisite epel repo
      yum:
        name: epel-release
        state: present

    - name: Install required packages
      yum:
        name: "{{ my_packages }}"
        state: present
```